# Modificando Valores de Várias Linhas

Tags: c#, mysql

Preciso de uma query que modifique vários valores ao mesmo tempo 
A ideia é mais ou menos essa

`"INSERT INTO registros(Envio) VALUES('1') where Aviso = '" + DdataAtual.Year + "-" + DdataAtual.Month + "-" + DdataAtual.Day + "' "`

A query está meio estranha por que está na ligação entre C# e MySql.
Como eu posso fazer isso ? Preciso modificar todos os valores que tenham uma certa data , ajuda ?

Comment: Yuri, atualizei minha resposta com uma solução para passar o parâmetro de forma mais segura e mais organizada, se quiser testar.

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer modificar ou alterar valores de uma tabela você utiliza o `UPDATE` e não o `INSERT`.

Exemplo:

```
UPDATE registros
SET Envio = '1'
WHERE Aviso = @dataFormatada
```

Trate sua data ao invés de ficar concatenando e se tiver utilizando `SqlCommand` passe como parâmetro. Dessa forma:

```
string sql = "UPDATE registros SET Envio = '1' WHERE Aviso = @dataFormatada;";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); /* conn = sua conexão */

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataFormatada", DdataAtual.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: NOoossa eu fui muito juvenil agora, obrigado !!!!!